# Delphi XE5 DataSnap application - feedback

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have developed a datasnap server in Delphi XE5.

one client connect to Server.

one client fire a method (lets say Server.ComputeTables  ).

the Server is doing some long computation in the method ComputeTables. 1,2,5 xx minutes.

how to send feedback to the client?  (a real feedback not ... "the server is doing something ... please wait").

like

server passed step 1

server passed step 2

server passed step 3

etc ...

Answer (score 3):

DataSnap supports callbacks. Pavel Glowacki has written nice [tutorials](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/pawelglowacki/2013/01/10/39958) about different aspects of DataSnap. Callbacks are explained in episode 11 of his Delphi Labs series.